# Add number one to a python list when the dimensions doesn't match

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, addition

Is it important to use `numpy` or not? But I tried to use it and didn't succeed.

This is the code:

```
c = []
a = list(range(10))
c.append(a)
b = list(range(5))
c.append(b)
```

How to add `1` to all the elements of `c`?

Comment: Are `a` and `b` supposed to be two different lists? As of now you have a list of two lists, you can use a list comprehension for to add one to each of the elements. If that is the case, see my answer below...

Comment: `c` is a list containing 2 lists.  "add 1" is not defined for a list.  Show `c` and show what result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use two list comprehensions to do what you desire. The outer loop iterates over the lists in `c`, and the inner loop iterates over the values in each list of `c`:

```py
c = []
a = list(range(10))
c.append(a)
b = list(range(5))
c.append(b)

[[val+1 for val in list] for list in c]
```

Comment: thanks , i was looking for an straght forward answer like a function or .+ like matlab!!!!!

Comment: How would you do this in MATLAB?  In Octave I have to make a `cell` of two matrices.  But then it complains that the '+' operator is defined for `cell` and `scalar`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this.

```
c = [[sum(x) for x in zip(y, [1]*len(y))] for y in c]
```

Comment: Using the example list in the question this didn't work for me. I got the error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'"